# Xpath expression for getting substring of a node without using substring-before or substring

Tags: java, xml, xpath

```xml
<tag1>
    <ResId Type="22" ID="MASTN_NHR" />
</tag1>
```

I want to get the string MASTN from the above xml(Java code). Do we have any option without using substring-before or substring?

Comment: Why can't you use the substring functions?

Comment: If you want to achieve something with one hand tied behind your back and wearing a blindfold, then it's a good idea to explain why you are restricted in this way, otherwise we have no motivation to help you with the task.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

this could work (XPath 2.0):

```
tokenize(@ID,'_')[1]
```